# How to disable eslint checking in webpack for create-react-app without ejecting?

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app@2.0.3` and I want to disable eslint checking in webpack without ejecting. I have used `react-app-rewired@2.0.2` for my purposes and my config looks like that

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  console.log(config.module.rules);
  return {
    ...config,
    module: {
      ...config.module,
      rules: [
        ...config.module.rules.filter(item => item.enforce !== 'pre'),
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

I wanted to remove eslint step by filtering rules, but it didn't help